# django json field: which one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-jsonfield

I am looking for a JSON field for Django.

I have found mainly 2 jsonfield app and I am not sure which one I should use.

The main difference I see is that the first one does not have the native JSON datatype support for PostgreSQL anymore.

It has been removed recently (https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield/commit/15957c9dab18c546ae5c119f8a6057e5db6b2135). It was related to this issue https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield/issues/57
but I am not sure if it's the right approach since JSONB is also coming soon with PostgreSQL 9.4. I think it's better to use the native datatype when using PostgreSQL. What do you think?

1) https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield

2) https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-jsonfield/

Comment: Sorry, recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 1.9 JSON support is back again with `JSONField`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/